# Page Sheet not displaying correctly after closing SFSafariViewController

Tags: swift4, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller as a page sheet. On this page sheet one of the buttons sends the user to a website using SFSafariViewController. When I select done in the SFSafariViewController the previous VC displays fullscreen and then snaps back to page sheet. How can I make it remain as a page sheet when the SFSafariVC is closed?

[Page Sheet before SFSafariVC called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3x5i.png)

[Immediately after clicking "done" in SFSafariVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk4F7.jpg)